# Можно ли говорить «абсолютно бесплатно»?

Tags: выбор-слов

Есть «бесплатно», и всё тут. Что значит еще добавка «абсолютно»?

Answer (score 1):

"Бесплатно" часто пишут со звёздочкой, то есть для получения необходимо выполнить какие-то условия, которые указываются самым мелким шрифтом.

"Абсолютно бесплатно" уже не может быть со звёздочкой.

А в плане логики вы правы: если бесплатно, то уже как бы бесплатнее стать не может. Но в языке сложилось иначе: "абсолютно бесплатно" указывает на бесплатность не только самого товара, а и всего процесса получения. Дело в том, что люди уже не сильно верят одному только слову "бесплатно". А "абсолютно" уже исправляет ситуацию.

Comment: Я не могу использовать в газетной статье звездочку, мы же не рекламу печатаем... Я убрала это «абсолютно» вон....

Comment: Тогда нужен пример, где вы убрали. А так вопрос выглядит общим, мол, вам просто интересно, а с делом не связано.

Comment: Мне интересно, почему так пишут...).... А текст о прививках...и о том, что сделать их можно абсолютно бесплатно.... И еще есть: эту постановку можно посмотреть абсолютно бесплатно.... С делом связано, потому что этих «абсолютно» полно в статьях..

Comment: В первом примере "абсолютно" кстати, потому что медики часто взимают деньги за что-то (например, за расходный материал), а во втором уже нет, там не должно быть дополнительных расходов, в связи с этим не сильно звучит (чуть избыточно). Примечание: даже порядок слов может играть роль (поэтому важно точно цитировать).

Comment: *Мне интересно, почему так пишут...)* — главная причина в том, что большинство людей уже не верят слову "бесплатно" (бесплатный сыр только в мышеловке).

Answer (score 0):

К «бесплатно» можно ещё прибавить условно доставку, установку, обслуживание и т.д. и т.п., а «абсолютно бесплатно» — подразумевается без дополнительных оплат и расходов.

Раньше реклама на диване была — купи сковородку, и в подарок, абсолютно бесплатно, получишь кастрюлю и сотейник.

Comment: Исправьте описку: *ра**с**ходов*.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец подразумевается -> что?   подразумевает -> кто? кого? ... разве не так?

Comment: Что-то подразумевает что-то. Или нужен знак препинания.

Comment: *разве не так?* — нет, не так. Фраза подразумевает что-то, а это что-то подразумевается под фразой.

Comment: @oleedd изначально было подразумевается, было изправлено на подразумевает... ПОДРАЗУМЕВАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв. что. Предполагать в мыслях, иметь в виду кого-, что-л.,

Comment: Короче, противоречите сами себе... иСправьте тогда уж *Обсолютно*.

Comment: С дополнительными расходами и доплатами это уже не бесплатно ...как бы.

Comment: @flossyU SIM-карта с абонтским номером выдаётся бесплатно, плата взымается за звонки, смс, интернет. сама "вещь" - бесплатно, обслуживание платно..... Ещё, помню в детсве, были журналы с футбольными и баскетбольными командами, куда надо было вклеивать картинки игроков. Журнал - бесплатно, а бустеры с наклейками приходилось покупать.

Comment: Это все понятно.... Покупаешь морковку за деньги, а нарезаешь ее бесплатно...)

Comment: @flossyU ага... помню лет десять в одном из супермаркетов наблюдал поистине шедевральную рекламу от одного банка - возьми у нас кредит и получи шариковую ручку для подписания догорова бесплатно.

Comment: ...Или купи квартиру, получи кепку)....

Comment: да... главное, что кепка бесплатно.

Comment: «абсолютно бесплатно»)